# How to calculate hour of time range with SQL Query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to calculate hour of time range with SQL Query.

The time accept are 08.00 - 12.00 AND 13.00-16.00

I have 2 columns with **start_time** , **end_time** in **time_table** Table

**Problem 1**

start_time = 08:00:00

end_time = '12:00:00'

Hour of time range = 4 hours from 08.00 - 12.00

**Problem 2**

start_time = '07:00:00'

end_time = '10:00:00'

Hour of time range = 2 hours from 08.00 - 10.00

**Problem 3**

start_time = '10:00:00'

end_time = '17:00:00'

Hour of time range = 5 hours from 10.00 - 12.00 AND 13.00 - 16.00

Thank you , Sharif

Comment: If you can change the table schema, consider having `start_time` and `end_time` cast as [`DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html), then you can use any number of built-in date-time functions, e.g. [`TIMEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

Comment: Now I used TIME can not?

Comment: I cannot see what advantage is provided by the date/time functions. This is a simple number line.

Comment: @Strawberry How do you propose difference computation of `08:00:00` and `12:00:00` with arithmetic operations without string manipulation? Of course my comment is void now that we know OP's schema uses `TIME`.

Comment: The example is TIME type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start_time and end_time are in integer for for easy to understand

```
SELECT id, SUM(hour) FROM (
    SELECT id, LEAST(12, end_time) - GREATEST(8, start_time) hour FROM `schedule` WHERE start_time<=12
    UNION
    SELECT id, LEAST(16, end_time) - GREATEST(13, start_time) hour FROM `schedule` WHERE end_time >=13
) x GROUP BY id
```

Comment: strong in this one the force is

Comment: Some row the time has minute also

Comment: you can store start_time and end_time in timestamp format or use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function to convert datetime to timestamp before comparison

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timediff function for the same.

Like 
syntax timediff(end_time,start_time);

`select timediff('12:00:00','08:00:00');` -- 04:00:00
`select timediff('10:00:00','07:00:00');` -- 03:00:00
`select timediff('17:00:00','10:00:00');` -- 07:00:00

if you want only hours to be returned then type as 
`select HOUR(timediff('12:00:00','08:00:00'));` -- 4
`select HOUR(timediff('10:00:00','07:00:00'));` -- 3
`select HOUR(timediff('17:00:00','10:00:00'));` -- 7

Comment: `SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)) FROM time_table;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('your_time_in_col', 'your_time_out_col') FROM yourtable WHERE your_key = 'your_key_value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the last problem...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,start_time INT NOT NULL
,end_time INT NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO my_table (start_time,end_time) VALUES
(8,12),(13,16),(10,17);

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +----+------------+----------+
 | id | start_time | end_time |
 +----+------------+----------+
 |  1 |          8 |       12 |
 |  2 |         13 |       16 |
 |  3 |         10 |       17 |
 +----+------------+----------+

                          3
        <----------------------------------->
        | 1        |   |       2       |
<------------------>   <--------------->
8   9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17

SELECT SUM(LEAST(x.end_time,y.end_time - GREATEST(x.start_time,y.start_time) )) diff
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON x.id <> y.id 
   AND x.end_time >= y.start_time 
   AND x.start_time < y.end_time 
 WHERE x.id = 3;

 +------+
 | diff |
 +------+
 |    5 |
 +------+
```